# Laravel Query Builder get only item with specific progress

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

**Good day, I'm trying to get orders with products that have a specific products progress.**

[image]

My Laravel query looks like this:

```
return Order::whereHas('products.progress', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('progress_id', 100)
        ->orWhereBetween('progress_id', [160, 240]);
      })
    ->with('products.progress')
    ->select('orders.id', 'orders.customer_id', 'orders.created_at')
    ->get();
```

In the query I set a where and whereBetween, the last Product has the **progress_id 50** that one should not be loaded into the order.

**How to do it? Thank you for reading.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you want to [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

so your (wheres) should be on the loading ...

```
return Order::with(['products'=>function($query){
        $query->whereHas('progress',function ($query){
            $query->where('progress_id', 100)
                ->orWhereBetween('progress_id', [160, 240]);
        })->with('progress');
    }])
        ->select('orders.id', 'orders.customer_id', 'orders.created_at')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Hello OMR, thank you for the response I have tried your solution and it only doesn't displays the progress relation. The product itself is still in the order.

Comment: Thank you very much OMR your solution is correct and very helpful.